# redirecting magento install in subfolder to subdomain

Tags: htaccess

I installed Magento in a sub-folder of my public HTML root but I cannot seem to get it to redirect from `example.com/shop` to `shop.example.com`.

I have tried to change the .htaccess file in the sub-folder. What happens is that the website redirects from `example.com/shop` to `shop.example.com` but now the store doesn't load.

I redirected the store originally using .htaccess file in the sub-folder to the subdomain but that didn't work and I tried to change the base URL and secure URL in Magento to no luck.

Please help!

Comment: i ended up using the example.com/shop

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried clearing magento server cache/session data? If not refer to the following article:

[How to clear the cache in Magento?](https://www.siteground.com/kb/how_to_clear_the_cache_in_magento/)

If the above doesn't work, have you checked if your http://shop.example.com DNS is being resolved? Have you put a static html file say test.html on the root of shop.example.com and see if you are able to browse http://shop.example.com/test.html?

By the way, you could have installed your magento directly under shop.example.com if you have permission to do that.

Comment: i tried changing the core_config_data in phpmyadmin with no luck. That is the first answer I have received and tried. Nothing. I also tried clearing cache. I installed the folder for my magento store under my public html folder so i have example.com/store. That works fine but redirecting to store.example.com messes everything up. Is there a way to install it at store.example.com that doesn't involve a redirect. I have access to my hosting and created the subdomain store.example.com which lives in the publichtml/store folder....maybe im making this too complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Go to database in table `core_config_data`

There are two row `web/secure/base_url` and `web/unsecure/base_url` add your store url  `http://shop.example.com/`

Clear cache and reindex all.

Comment: i tried changing the core_config_data in phpmyadmin with no luck. That is the first answer I have received and tried. Nothing. I also tried clearing cache. I installed the folder for my magento store under my public html folder so i have example.com/store. That works fine but redirecting to store.example.com messes everything up. Is there a way to install it at store.example.com that doesn't involve a redirect. I have access to my hosting and created the subdomain store.example.com which lives in the publichtml/store folder....maybe im making this too complicated.